# load data into ng-repeat according to tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what I want is each of tab consist of its dynamic content, but now I doubt I was doing it correctly when I put ng-view within ng-repeat.

Here's a working version to push 
http://plnkr.co/edit/19sAXoEW4HZ9G7CT7R3a?p=preview

I've to load some data, I hardly can find a way to allocate items correctly according to tabs.

the tab isn't working anymore
http://plnkr.co/edit/jbxypSlvk3rYlFAIHygo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this is to have what you're trying to include in the ng-view as a directive.  I moved the task list into a taskform directive with an isolate scope.  You'll see now each tracks it's tasks separately and tabs can be added/removed which include the taskform with it's own scope.

Here's the plunk, take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/8gxOlR0vXxacGDdVVe0W?p=preview